# Генерация JAR исполняемого файла в Intelij Idea 2017.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Доброго времени суток, такой вопрос, при генерации jar файла в  Idea 2017.3 jre-9.0.4 сам jar файл не исполняемый, т.е. при его запуске ничего не происходит, вообще, даже ошибки не выдает. в META-INF main класc прописан. Main класс является классом GUI-form, может проблема в этом? До этого в версии Idea 16 и jre-8 подобных проблем не возникало, как пофиксить?
Починил через мавен, был не верно задан путь для main класса, который включает в себя GUI-form, но вопрос так же не снят, почему не запускается jar  сгенерированый Idea. Полезные ссылкки:
https://dev64.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/executable-jar-maven/
https://dev64.wordpress.com/2012/05/16/build-jar-with-dependencies-with-maven/ 
MAIN метод

```
   import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by ApotinV on 05.02.2018.
 */
public class Window extends JFrame{
    private JTextField input;
    private JPanel rootPanel;
    private JButton Button2;
    private JButton Button1;
    private String tInput;

    public Window() {
        setContentPane(rootPanel);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                int ret = fileChooser.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    input.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });
        Button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tInput = input.getText();
                ESExcel esExcel = null;
                ArrayList<ESExcel> listESExcel = null;
                ArrayList<ESExcel> listESExcel2 = null;
                ArrayList<ArrayList<ESExcel>> listLists = null;

                try {
                    listESExcel = Parser.parseXlsx(tInput);

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvalidFormatException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

               listESExcel2 = ESExcel.checkCorrect(listESExcel);
               listLists = ESExcel.checkND(listESExcel);


               ESExcel.writeIntoExcel(tInput, listESExcel, listESExcel2,listLists);
            }
        });

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Window();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте запустить jar файл из cmd. `java -jar C:/jar.jar`

Comment: Такая же штука, он просто его не запускает, выполнено, но не запущено

Comment: Может ли быть проблема в maven? Jar файл из мавена, так же не запускается, ничего не происходит

Comment: покажите код с main методом

Comment: Добавил маин метод